# How to rotate image in android using android ndk

Tags: c, image-processing, android-ndk

i want to rotate bitmap in android . i don't want to use android api but want to use c code for image processing and fast response. can u tell me how to achieve this in c??

Thank you  in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could use [OpenCV for Android](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Android) by processing a rotation matrix in native code. But if you really just want to rotate an image, using native code for this would be over the top, unless you plan adding more complex transformations. A single transformation supposedly won't be processed faster in comparison to just rotating it in Java.

Comment: thank you for reply ,, but it is first step for me to rotate image then i can do resize , apply some filter , crop image  all this complex operation i want to do through native code because i want to avoid memory exception as well as to boost process . i think i have to apply some algorithm for rotation .if you know more in this , just tell me

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice solution for your needs: ImageMagick. You can compile C version of ImageMagick with NDK. There is also [ImageMagick-Android](https://github.com/lilac/Android-ImageMagick) project on github, but it doesn't look like a ready-to-use solution.